# How to find constant bandwith in application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Team

i have to find the constant bandwith when i am login and usuing application till i am not log out...

i have try this code but it gives only one time speed i want constant speed track of bandwith ..

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.downloadSpeedMeasure.active = YES;
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
 {

 }];
// to avoid a retain cycle one has to pass a weak reference to operation into the progress block.
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
     float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    NSLog(@"%f",progress);
    double speedInBytesPerSecond = operation.downloadSpeedMeasure.speed;
    NSString *humanReadableSpeed = operation.downloadSpeedMeasure.humanReadableSpeed;
    double humanReadableSpeed1 = operation.downloadSpeedMeasure.speed;


   // NSTimeInterval remainingTimeInSeconds = [operation.downloadSpeedMeasure remainingTimeOfTotalSize:totalBytesExpectedToRead numberOfCompletedBytes:totalBytesRead];
   // NSString *humanReadableRemaingTime = [operation.downloadSpeedMeasure humanReadableRemainingTimeOfTotalSize:totalBytesExpectedToRead numberOfCompletedBytes:totalBytesRead];
    NSLog(@"humanReadableSpeed : %@",humanReadableSpeed);
    NSLog(@"humanReadableSpeed : %f",humanReadableSpeed1);

    //NSLog(@"speedInBytesPerSecond : %f",speedInBytesPerSecond);

}];
[operation start];
```

can any one help me to find out how to get constant bandwith  using any third party libs,functuion,demo????

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Given that bandwidth is how many bytes have been sent or received in some amount of time (sort of a speed of downloading or uploading), could you clarify what "constant speed" would mean? Is that an average speed between download operations, is it an average speed for the duration when the app is running, is it some sort of, say, a low pass filter or something else? Perhaps you could elaborate what it will be used for?